# API Platform - remove password hash from result

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, api-platform.com

I have User entity that cointains attributes like: id, email, password...

**Password** attribute is a password hash, and I would like to remove it from GET result from item and collection operations.

Is there any annotation for this? ( I tried *@ApiProperty (readable=false)*, but without success)

I suppose I can remove password from result through event subscriber but I am curious if there is any simple way how to achieve it.

Comment: Search for serialization settings. Either using serialization group or ignoring properties. Apiplatform uses Symfony Serializer, but I don't know how it is configured there.

Comment: Yeah serialization groups are the way. Thanks @svgrafov !

Comment: Consider answering this question yourself if you can, this is permitted and even encouraged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the **Groups** in Entity

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(attributes={
 *     "normalization_context"={"groups"={"read"}},
 *     "denormalization_context"={"groups"={"write"}}
 * })
 */
```

```
class User {
/**
  * @Groups("write")
  * @ORM\Column(..........)
  */
private $password;
```

Doc: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization#using-serialization-groups